# Django POST method using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

Im trying to do a POST request using JQuery but my JQuery scripts fails when I add the .ajax call.

When I remove the ajax calls the alert method is displayed without any problems.

Question:

What would be the syntax error or possible other errors?

```
$("#table_appl,#table_enfr,#table_det01,#table_det02,#table_det03,#table_det04,#table_det05,#table_datais").on( "click", "input:submit", function( event ) {
            alert('Hi')
            //event.preventDefault();

              $.ajax({

                    type:"POST",

                    url:"/validate/"

                    success:function(data){
                        alert(data);
                    }

               });

            return false;

        })
```

Comment: The url seems sketchy, you sure it's the right one? Also, shouldn't you specify `data` in an `$.ajax` call? Plus, you don't have any `,` after the `url` specification.

Comment: The commas were the problem..damn it...Thanks

Comment: So it sends the data without you specifying `data`?

Comment: I get a 403 error now..I think its related to the csrf token...

Comment: where do you have the page you're posting to?

Comment: Please update the question or create a new one.

Comment: @lisik; it's been sent to a django view. Is that your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things I would change:

**1.** Change:

```
"input:submit"
```

to:

```
'input[type="submit"]'
```

**2.** Change:

```
url:"/validate/"
```

to:

```
url:"/validate/",
```

**3.** Specify `data` in your `$.ajax` call.